# Enable VLAN and set VLAN ID with powershell script if VLAN is not yet enabled

Tags: powershell, networking, ethernet, vlan, windows-11

I'm right now trying to write a powershell script in Windows 11, that should automatically configure an usb to ethernet adapter. For this I need to automatically configure the VLAN of the adapter.

Everything works fine in case the VLAN was already activated in the network dialog using

```
Set-NetAdapter -Name Adapter -VlanID 999
```

In case the network adapter is not yet configured the script fails with:

```
Set-NetAdapter : Requested operation not supported on adapter
```

The screenshot* shows on how to disable VLAN on the adapter:

[image: VLAN is disabled in network settings]

Does anyone knows how to enable VLAN with powershell in the first place prior to setting the VLAN ID?

**"Nicht vorhanden" = Unavailable*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the following command:

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty
```

If you test with this you should be able to tell what property needs to be set e.g.

```
 Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -DisplayName "Jumbo*" -DisplayValue "4088 Bytes"
```